# How to display 2 phrases in a single line , one center aligned ,the other right aligned in html?

Tags: html, css, alignment

I want to display the following heading line in HTML:

```
                         Hello World                  HTML Example
```

"Hello World" is center aligned while "HTML Example" is right aligned.
Which HTML element should I use?

I've tried using span element and the display:inline css style but the two phrases always display in two separate lines.

HTML`<h4 align="center" > Hello World <span align="right" > HTML Example </span></h4>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully it's what you're trying to achieve:

```html
<h4 align="center"> Hello World <span style="float:right;"> HTML Example </span></h4>
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
<h4 align="center" ><span style="float:left;margin-left:30%"> Hello World</span> <span align="right" style="float:right;margin-right:30%"> HTML Example </span></h4>
```